# Why does ScrollView make the screen go up?

Tags: react-native, scrollview

When I use `ScrollView` the screen goes up and even scrolls but doesn't work. when I use `KeyboardAvoidingView` it has same issue. What is the problem?

```
export default function AuthLayout({ children }) {
  const dismissKeyboard = () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        onPress={dismissKeyboard}
        disabled={Platform.OS === "web"}
      >
        <SAuthLayout>{children}</SAuthLayout>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}
```

Screen shot of my app and the gray part below is the space that has the `ScrollView`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per memory you should encapsulate your `ScrollView` with a `View` and your `flex`:

```
export default function AuthLayout({ children }) {
  const dismissKeyboard = () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <ScrollView>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        onPress={dismissKeyboard}
        disabled={Platform.OS === "web"}
      >
        <SAuthLayout>{children}</SAuthLayout>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried that. but it shows the same screen.

Comment: Let me check my notes I want to say there is a reason for this and why I used `FlatList`

Comment: If I use FlatList, it shows just a white screen.

Comment: Ya there's a certain process I ran across from this. On mobile but when I get back I'll check my repo of react native notes. If you edit your question with sample data I can build a better example

Comment: can you help me? or just give me some clues?

Comment: where is your repo link?

Comment: my full code: https://github.com/hayatshin/chungchunon-native.git

Comment: components/auth/AuthLayout has `ScrollView` or `KeyBoardAvoidingView` component. Both cause the same problem. Thanks a lot for your help.